# In Spring Quartz what is ThreadPriority?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

The documentation about `threadPriority` states the following:

> Can be any int between Thread.MIN_PRIORITY (which is 1) and Thread.MAX_PRIORITY (which is 10). The default is Thread.NORM_PRIORITY (5).

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.2/configuration/ConfigThreadPool.html

My questions is what is the purpose of this setting? Let's say I set it to `10` what would be the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets the thread priority of worker threads in the pool. Similar to the [method](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/simpl/SimpleThreadPool.html#setThreadPriority(int)) on the default thread pool.

Each `Thread` in Java has a priority value you can set. See [setPriority(int newPriority)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority-int-).

> Every thread has a priority. Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority. Each thread may or may not also be marked as a daemon. When code running in some thread creates a new Thread object, the new thread has its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread, and is a daemon thread if and only if the creating thread is a daemon.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

See also [Recommended Coding Practices](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs142/devapp/codeprac.html#998533)

> #### Don't Depend on Thread Priorities
>
> Be careful when using java.lang.Thread.setPriority. Depending on thread priorities might lead on unwanted or unexpected results since the scheduling algorithm might choose to starve lower priority threads of CPU time and never execute them. Furthermore the result might differ between operating systems and JVMs.
>
> The Java API specification states that "Every thread has a priority. Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority."
>
> **The priority set by the setPriority() method is a parameter that might be used in the thread-scheduling algorithm, which shares CPU execution time between executing threads. This algorithm might be controlled either by the JVM or by the operating system. It is important to be aware of the fact that this algorithm normally differs between operating systems and that the algorithm might change between releases of both the operating system and the JVM. For BEA JRockit JVM native threads, the algorithm is implemented by the operating system.**